# Error when trying to establish a MVC connection to SQL Server 2012 (localdb) running on my PC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have set up my web.config like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source='C:\Users\Marilou\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\authentication.mdf';Initial Catalog=javacert;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=yyy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But I am getting the message:

```
   Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
   Source=EntityFramework
   StackTrace:
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
        at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        HResult=-2146232060
        Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
        Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
        ErrorCode=-2146232060
```

Comment: SQL Server version? Honestly when in doubt I just check http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I can't find much on how to connect to the new (localdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using LocalDB. From this MSDN article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx), the connection string is as follows :

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\MyData\Database1.mdf".
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try that now.